# Should I add ID attributes to every element in XML?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-attributes

Even if I don't reference them, should I add an `android:id` attribute to every element in my XML layout files?

I've asked elsewhere and was given this answer:

> Views that don't have an ID specified won't have their state automatically persisted / restored by the system. *[...]*  If you have an edit text that doesn't have an android:id then if you rotate the screen then the text in the edit text will be cleared out

So in that sense, it makes me think that it's not necessary.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer, you should put an ID for every view that you want to keep state.

For example, you don't need to bother to keep state of a TextView that have an atribute android:text that don't is changed.

But you probably want to keep the state of an EditText that the user has filled with info. You can keep the state in two ways:

1. Implementing the onSaveInstanceState, putting the content of the editText inside the bundle and getting this bundle in the onCreate and fill the editText with the info.
2. Put an id and let android keep the track for you.

So, in resume, put ids for views that you want to bind and for views that you want to android to track the state for you.